# Get guild ID from on_message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm currently trying to make a server prefix system using json.

I'm trying to get the prefix from the prefixes.json file but I get this:

[image: picture of error]

[This is the on_message I'm using](https://pastebin.com/raw/18vkHSRY)

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '<@754643724193235035>' == message.content:
        channel = message.channel
        a = open('prefixes.json', 'r')
        serverprefix = json.load(a)
        await channel.send("My prefix is:")
        await channel.send(serverprefix['message.guild.id'])
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

[This is the json I'm using](https://pastebin.com/raw/UKdSaxx6)

```
{
    "712329859562315886": ";",
    "709202272655118233": "~"
}
```

There's also been another thing bugging me, how could I add serverprefix['message.guild.id'] to a f""?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the error is you try to get a value from a key named `message.guild.id`. Obviously there is no key with that name. So you have to use string fromatting.

You should change `await channel.send(serverprefix['message.guild.id'])` to `await channel.send(serverprefix[f'{message.guild.id}'])`. So you can get the prefix from json file.